# How to generate a image file from base 64 string in Lua?

Tags: image, lua, base64

I can  get the base 64 string from WCF ,and need to convert it into image file by Lua?
Any one have idea about this?

thanks

Comment: Lua by itself does not have any notion of image. You need to improve your question and tell on what context and platform you use Lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this with LuaSocket:

```
local ltn12 = require "ltn12"
local mime = require "mime"

mystring = "somedata"
myoutfile = "out.gif"

ltn12.pump.all(
  ltn12.source.string(mystring),
  ltn12.sink.chain(
    mime.decode("base64"),
    ltn12.sink.file(io.open(outfile,"w"))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a base64 C library for Lua at http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lbase64.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using luarocks:

```
luarocks install lbase64
```

Also check this out:

https://github.com/LuaDist/lbase64